# Combine observable responses into one

Tags: javascript, react-native, promise, redux-observable

How can I obtain an object response from multiple observables?

My Epic is likes this:

```
export function metaDataEpic(action$: ActionsObservable<metaDataActions>) { 
    return action$.ofType(META_DATA_REQUEST)
      .mergeMap((action: metaDataActions) => {
        const { language } = action;
        return Observable.merge(
          Observable.fromPromise(couriersApi().then(r => r.json())),
          Observable.fromPromise(itemCategoriesApi({ language }).then(r => r.json())),
          Observable.fromPromise(airportsApi().then(r => r.json())))
          .flatMap(res => {
            console.log(res);
            return Observable.of(getMetaDataSuccess({}))
          });
      });
}
```

What I need is to pass my function `getMetaDataSuccess()` an object with the responses from `courierApi()`, `itemCategoriesApi()` and `airportsApi()` like this `getMetaDataSuccess({ couriers, items, airports })` but first i need to wait for all 3 promises to finish and somehow combine in an object as response.

What my code does now is print the responses from the API's and thus calling `getMetaDataSuccess` 3 times. `enter code here`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like you want something like this.

```
export function metaDataEpic(action$: ActionsObservable<metaDataActions>) { 
    return action$.ofType(META_DATA_REQUEST)
      .flatMap(({language}) => Promise.all([
            couriersApi(),
            itemCategoriesApi({language}),
            airportsApi()
          ].map(p => p.then(r => r.json()))
        )
        .then(([couriers, items, airports]) => ({couriers, items, airports}))
      )
      .do(console.log)
      .map(getMetaDataSuccess);
}
```

`flatMap` aka `mergeMap` can operate directly on Promise and Arraylike values. Here we are using `Promise.all` to wait for the results of multiple Promises. `Promise.all` returns a Promise that resolves to an array where each element is the result of the corresponding item in the input array. We transform this array into an object and pass it along.

Here it is in action with dummy data demonstrating that it works.

```js
function couriersApi() {
  return Promise.resolve({
    json: () => [{
      name: 'x',
      id: 1
    }, {
      name: 'y',
      id: 2
    }]
  });
}

function airportsApi() {
  return Promise.resolve({
    json: () => [{
      name: 'ORF',
      id: 1
    }, {
      name: 'JFK',
      id: 2
    }]
  });
}

function itemCategoriesApi({language}) {
  return Promise.resolve({
    json: () => [{
        name: 'a',
        language: 'German'
      },
      {
        name: 'b',
        language: 'English'
      },
    ].filter(c => c.language === language)
  });
}
const META_DATA_REQUEST = undefined;
const action$ = {
  ofType: () => Rx.Observable.of({
    language: 'English'
  })
};

metaDataEpic(action$)
  .subscribe();

function getMetaDataSuccess(o) {
  console.log(o.couriers);
  console.log(o.items);
  console.log(o.airports);
}

function metaDataEpic(action$) {
  return action$.ofType(META_DATA_REQUEST)
    .flatMap(({
        language
      }) => Promise.all([
        couriersApi(),
        itemCategoriesApi({
          language
        }),
        airportsApi()
      ].map(p => p.then(r => r.json())))
      .then(([couriers, items, airports]) => ({
        couriers,
        items,
        airports
      }))
    )
    .do(console.log)
    .map(getMetaDataSuccess);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/rxjs/5.5.6/Rx.js"></script>
```

Comment: You are missing a parenthesis at `r.json())` for `Promise.all(`
Also, I tried but console.log was never hit

Comment: @user3610155 thanks, I fixed the typo and added a live demo. Run it, it works.

Answer (score 1):

I have two solutions on my mind, you can try if they work in your case:

```
export function metaDataEpic(action$: ActionsObservable<metaDataActions>) {
    return action$
    .ofType(META_DATA_REQUEST)
    .mergeMap((action: metaDataActions) => {
        const {language} = action;

        const requestObservable = Observable.zip(
            Observable.fromPromise(couriersApi().then(r => r.json())),
            Observable.fromPromise(
                itemCategoriesApi({language}).then(r => r.json())
            ),
            Observable.fromPromise(airportsApi().then(r => r.json())),
            (couriers, items, airports) => {
                return Observable.of(getMetaDataSuccess({ couriers, items, airports })) ).map(response => response.value)
            }
        ).catch(e => {
            return Observable.of(getMetaDataFail(e));
        });

        return requestObservable;
    });
}
```

or

```
export function metaDataEpic(action$: ActionsObservable<metaDataActions>) {
    return action$
    .ofType(META_DATA_REQUEST)
    .mergeMap((action: metaDataActions) => {
        const {language} = action;

        Promise.all(
            [couriersApi(), itemCategoriesApi({language}), airportsApi()].map(p =>
                p.then(r => r.json())
            )
        )
        .then(([couriers, items, airports]) => {
            return Observable.of(getMetaDataSuccess({couriers, items, airports}));
        })
        .catch(e => {
            return Observable.of(getMetaDataFail(e));
        });
    });
}
```

Comment: I ended up using this because of the rxjs. Although I had to add a `.map(response => response.value` to the zip to get an action

Comment: I see can you try `return getMetaDataSuccess({couriers, items, airports}); ` instead `return Observable.of(getMetaDataSuccess({couriers, items, airports}));`

Comment: I had to use both to make it work
Like this:
    `return Observable.zip(
          Observable.fromPromise(couriersApi().then(r => r.json())),
          Observable.fromPromise(itemCategoriesApi({ language }).then(r => r.json())),
          (couriers, itemCategories) => Observable.of(getMetaDataSuccess({ couriers, itemCategories }))
        ).map(response => response.value)`